# Wordpress Max Mega Menu, want to add separate class on sticky navbar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class, sticky

How can I add a class that only applies when the sticky navbar menu activated in WordPress? I need a separate class that triggers only when sticky activated. Right now I am using Max Meta Menu Plugin for the navigation bar.
[this is for normal view without scrolling the page][1]

[after scrolling of page sticky applied but here I want one more class for adjusting additional css][2]

can I add the class directly from theme customization?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfRUD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WVqh.png

Comment: You should be able to add a class to any element with `window.onscroll` Depending on the theme you are using. Some themes allow you to add JS in the customizer section. Otherwise you can open the footer.php file of your theme or the functions js file and add your code in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll >= 200) {
        $(".selector").addClass(".yourclass");
    } else {
        $(".selector").removeClass(".yourclass");
    }
});
```

With some themes they allow you to add JS in the customizer. Otherwise you can open the theme footer.php file or place it in the functions.js file.

You also get plugins to inject JS code for you like this one - https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/

First check if your theme does not allow you to add custom JS

Another option is to check if your element has a class

```
      // CHECK IF YOUR NAV HAS GOT THE STICKY CLASS
      if ( $( .your_nav_selector ).hasClass('sticky') ) {
            // ADD YOUR NEW CLASS TO SOME OTHER (OR SAME) SELECTOR
            $( .selector ).addClass( 'yourclassname' );         
        }
    });
```